# sed: Referring to parts of the matching pattern

Tags: unix, sed

I try to replace a version nummber on all lines which contain the pattern something like: `moduleprop`

```
    <module name="XYZ_Web">
        <moduleprop name="war" value="xyzz-web-2.23.12-SNAPSHOT.war"/>
        <moduleprop name="starting_weight" value="6000"/>
        <moduleprop name="virtualHost" value="default_host"/>
    </module>
    <module name="XYZ_Export_EJB">
        <moduleprop name="jar" value="xyzl-export-ejb-2.23.12-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
        <moduleprop name="starting_weight" value="1000"/>
    </module>
```

My sed command finds all the lines I'm looking for:

```
sed 's/<moduleprop name="[j|w]ar" value="xyz[z|l]-[a-z-]*2\.23\.12-SNAPSHOT\.[j|w]ar"\/>/test/g' my-file.xml
```

With this aproach, I can't refer back to each regex and use the value. I tried to refer with \1 \2 but my cygwin complains with:

```
sed: -e Ausdruck #1, Zeichen 25: Ungültiger Verweis \1 im rechten Teil (`RHS') des `s'-Befehls
```

Comment: *to replace a version nummber on all lines* - what is the replacement value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have parts of the matched string to refer to with `\1` etc, you need to capture them.  In classic `sed`, you use `\(` to start a capture, and `\)` to end it.  The captures are numbered in sequence by the appearance of the `\(` markers.

You might use:

```
sed 's/\(<moduleprop name="[j|w]ar" value="xyz[z|l]-[a-z-]*\)\(2\.23\.12-SNAPSHOT\)\(\.[j|w]ar"\/>\)/1=\1; 2=\2; 3=\3/g' my-file.xml
```

If need be, captures can be nested.